# "Filename too long" in sbt assembly inside a docker container

Tags: scala, docker, sbt, sbt-assembly

I have a scala Play project and I need to create a fat jar in the docker build time but I get this error:

`[warn] Error extracting zip entry [...] (File name too long)`

I tried adding the option `scalacOptions ++= Seq("-Xmax-classfile-name","72")` in *build.sbt* but doesn't works. I tried also appending `-Xmax-classfile-name=72` to `sbt assembly` with the same result.

As I need to do it in docker build time, I can't use a mounted volume as mentioned here https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly/issues/69#issuecomment-196901781

What do I need to do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

In /project/plugins.sbt

```
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.13.0")
```

and in build.sbt

```
assemblyJarName in assembly := "jarname.jar"
target in assembly := baseDirectory.value
```

Then run command "assembly" from project root and should generate the jar file.